# How to event click on DIV except if the clicked element is a specific one

Tags: javascript

I have a div with several elements. I want to make an event to handle clicking on any element of this div, EXCEPT a specific one.

```
<div id="mydiv">
<img id="myimage" src="myimage.gif"/>
<img id="myimage2" src="myimage2.gif"/>
<img id="myimage3" src="myimage3.gif"/>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('click', function() {
// if element is not the one with id=myimage3 do something
alert('You clicked on image1 or image2');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `event` parameter to the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventtarget/addeventlistener#the_event_listener_callback) and check that its targets `id` attribute is not `myimage3`:

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'myimage3')
    alert('You clicked on image1 or image2');
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=image1" />
  <img id="myimage2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=image2" />
  <img id="myimage3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=image3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass 'event' as an argument to the callback function.

Wrap the alert in an if statement checking if the

```
event.target.id !== 'myimage3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements in HTML can be identified is a few different ways: by `class` and by `id`. `Class`es are collections of elements that can be selected, styled, and further manipulated whereas `id`s are unique are should be specific to a single element. Since you want to exclude a specific element from being selected, you'll need to compare the selected element's id with that of the one you wish to exclude.

This can be done with a callback like in @Nick 's answer using the `event.target` property.

Essentially what `e.target` does is it gets the element which triggered the event and all of its various attributes eg. `tagName` and `style`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#example